# How to translate data values in kendo grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, localization, kendo-grid

I want to translate data values in kendo grid, tried something like this:

```
<div id="myDiv" kendo-grid k-data-source="controller.items"
   k-columns='[{ "field": "status", "title": "Status", "template": "{{dataItem.status | translate}}" ]]'>
```

But it's not working.

What is the right way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: can you put the complete code (jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute shouldn't be `k-columns` but `data-columns`

Comment: The part that is not working is translation, grid is showing untranslated data.